# Runtime error 3061 Microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a problem in Microsoft access. When I try compare the value with all values in the Subform, it's always show the error 3061: `too few parameters expected 1.`

Here is my code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete from clubs " & _
                        "  WHERE club_name =" & Me.subClubForms.Form.Recordset.Fields("club_name")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `club_name` is a TEXT field then you have to filter by string:

```
"  WHERE club_name ='" & Me.subClubForms.Form.Recordset.Fields("club_name").Value & "'"
```

Comment: Vulnerable to SQL injection, or even just a single quote in the data value. You should be escaping the string.